# how to draw a grid incrementally in d3?

Tags: d3.js

Below is an HTML file that will draw a 10x10 grid of squares alternating light grey and dark grey.  It fills a 2d array called `the_grid` with 0 or 1; then fills a 1d array called `nodes` with `x`, `y`, and `color`; then draws `nodes` with d3.  They all appear.  They look like this:

[image: grid of squares]

How do I instead have `nodes` drawn (i.e. appear) one at a time, in the order given by the `nodes` array (so I could draw different patterns, say vertical wipe, horizontal wipe, whatever)?

I tried fiddling with the `transition` function without success.  It just draws the whole grid, and slides it into place.  The squares don't visibly appear one by one.

The code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function draw_function() {
          var vis = d3.select("#graph")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

          // fill the_grid
          var shape=[10,10];
          var the_grid=[];
          for (var idx = 0; idx < shape[0]; idx++) {
              var row = [];
              for (var jdx = 0; jdx < shape[1]; jdx++) {
                  var val = (idx+jdx)/2;
                  row.push(Math.floor(val)==val ? 1 : 0);
              }
              the_grid.push(row);
          }

          // fill nodes
          var rectwidth = 10;
          var nodes = [];
          for (var idx = 0; idx < the_grid.length; idx++) {
              for (var jdx = 0; jdx < the_grid[0].length; jdx++) {
                  var node = {x: idx * (rectwidth+1),
                              y: jdx * (rectwidth+1),
                              color: the_grid[idx][jdx] == 1 ? 'black' : 'lightgrey'};
                  nodes.push(node);
              }
          }

          // draw nodes
          vis.selectAll("rect.nodes")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("svg:rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr("height", rectwidth)
              .attr("width", rectwidth)
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
      }

      // function has to execute after dom is loaded
      window.onload = draw_function
    </script>

    <style>rect { color: black; }</style>
  </head>

  <body><div id="graph"/></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stagger the transitions of multiple elements entered at the same time from the same data array you can use `transition.delay()`, you can specify a constant (which will start all transitions simutaneously) or you can specify a function to base the delay on the datum of each element or its index:

```
selection.transition()
  .delay(function(d,i) { return i * 100; })
  .attr(...
```

Above and in the snippet below I've used the index:

```js
function draw_function() {
          var vis = d3.select("#graph")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

          // fill the_grid
          var shape=[10,10];
          var the_grid=[];
          for (var idx = 0; idx < shape[0]; idx++) {
              var row = [];
              for (var jdx = 0; jdx < shape[1]; jdx++) {
                  var val = (idx+jdx)/2;
                  row.push(Math.floor(val)==val ? 1 : 0);
              }
              the_grid.push(row);
          }

          // fill nodes
          var rectwidth = 10;
          var nodes = [];
          for (var idx = 0; idx < the_grid.length; idx++) {
              for (var jdx = 0; jdx < the_grid[0].length; jdx++) {
                  var node = {x: idx * (rectwidth+1),
                              y: jdx * (rectwidth+1),
                              color: the_grid[idx][jdx] == 1 ? 'black' : 'lightgrey'};
                  nodes.push(node);
              }
          }

          // draw nodes
          vis.selectAll("rect.nodes")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("svg:rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr("height", rectwidth)
              .attr("width", rectwidth)
              .attr("fill","white")
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .delay(function(d,i) { return i * 100; })
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
      }

      // function has to execute after dom is loaded
      window.onload = draw_function
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"/>
```

And below I've used the datum to create a random transition order:

```js
function draw_function() {
          var vis = d3.select("#graph")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

          // fill the_grid
          var shape=[10,10];
          var the_grid=[];
          for (var idx = 0; idx < shape[0]; idx++) {
              var row = [];
              for (var jdx = 0; jdx < shape[1]; jdx++) {
                  var val = (idx+jdx)/2;
                  row.push(Math.floor(val)==val ? 1 : 0);
              }
              the_grid.push(row);
          }

          // fill nodes
          var rectwidth = 10;
          var nodes = [];
          for (var idx = 0; idx < the_grid.length; idx++) {
              for (var jdx = 0; jdx < the_grid[0].length; jdx++) {
                  var node = {
                              delay: Math.random()*2000,
                              x: idx * (rectwidth+1),
                              y: jdx * (rectwidth+1),
                              color: the_grid[idx][jdx] == 1 ? 'black' : 'lightgrey'};
                  nodes.push(node);
              }
          }

          // draw nodes
          vis.selectAll("rect.nodes")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("svg:rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
              .attr("height", rectwidth)
              .attr("width", rectwidth)
              .attr("fill","white")
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .delay(function(d,i) { return d.delay; })
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
      }

      // function has to execute after dom is loaded
      window.onload = draw_function
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"/>
```

Comment: great! the secret seems to be the "delay" function, and putting it in the right spot. duration is unneeded.

Comment: I used duration just to slow the transition itself a bit, but yes, it is not needed (But I goofed, I set initial fill to `none`, I've updated it to `white` so that d3 can interpolate between start and end values without further modification){

Comment: will it draw in `nodes` order, or do i have to set the delays to the right values to reveal them in order?

Comment: If using the index of the node in the data array (`i * time`), the transitions will always start in same order as they are in the array.