# d3 - Show data nodes one at a time through transitional delays

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, transition

Basically I have a line graph with several data points.  I want to display these data points (or circles) one after the other as the line in which the nodes is drawn.  However, I can't figure out how to chain it so that they only display one at a time.  Instead, they're all showing at once.  Any thoughts on the issue?  This is my code that shows them:

```
d3.selectAll('circle').each(function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).transition().delay(3000).duration(2500).style('opacity', 1);
});
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990733/7106086)? Or where only one node is visible at a time?

Comment: Before doing this, make sure to set the opacity for all the circles to 0 as well, otherwise it will be transitioning between 1 and 1.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks Andrew!